# Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion in edit form codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

hi i am using codeigniter 3.0 i have an edit option in my category page.

i given the following code in controller and model .

---

controller:

```
public function categories_edit($data) {

    //$data['categories'] = array();
    $data['$result'] = $this->work_category->getcategory($data);

    $this->load->view('admin/category/category',$data); 
}
```

---

model:

```
public function getcategory($data){

            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nw_category WHERE category_id = '$data' ");

            return $query->row();

        }
```

---

The above code showing the

> Severity: Notice
>       Message: Array to string conversion

how to get the the row and send the view file..

I am in  Beginner in codeigniter please help me to solve this issue thank u

Comment: What is within `$data`. Post that too

Comment: you call  `getcategory($data)` with data as array but it must be `id`

Comment: the category id. i get this id from my list of category in view page

Comment: `print_r($data)`  in your controller or model file and paste the result of it!!!

Comment: No you have too show us what data inside `$data` variable!!!

Comment: now i change my sql query to $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nw_category WHERE category_id = '".$data['category_id']."' ");
return $query->row(); but it showing the Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query has issue:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nw_category WHERE category_id = '$data' ");
```

`$data` is array, where as SQL is expecting it to be string or integer.

**Solution:**

First print the `$data` inside the said function.

Try to find out which array element is `category_id` and replace it in SQL.

So, the new SQL should be:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nw_category WHERE category_id = '" . $data['category_id'] . "'");
```

Comment: if i give $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nw_category WHERE category_id = '".$data['category_id']."' ");  it showing the same error

Comment: now i change my sql query to $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM nw_category WHERE category_id = '".$data['category_id']."' "); return $query->row(); but it showing the Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string